# Relative hyperlink paths in ArcMap 10 Map Document Properties?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, hyperlink

Is there a way to use relative paths (instead of absolute paths) in the "Hyperlink base" field in Map Document Properties for an ArcMap 10 map document?

(I have "Store relative pathnames to data sources" checked, but somehow I still can't use relative pathnames in Hyperlink base)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you check the [Making hyperlinks with relative paths](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s500000004000000.htm) link in the help file?  Are the hyperlinks truly relative to the location of your *.mxd?

Comment: This answer helped me greatly. Just to add on, I'm sending out a map package with an accompanying folder of images. The person receiving these files will only need to update the hyperlink base, correct?  **edit** I understand this question now, and got a true relative hyperlink base working. Thanks again!

Comment: It is clear when the location of hyperlinked documents is at the same level as or deeper than the mxd. What about if it is one level up? I couldnt find the syntax. My structure is +documents folder
|_images folder map folder
|_mxd file My documents are one level up in images folder.
I tried \documets folder\images folder\
..\documets folder\images folder\ but none worked.